# How to use multi required_if in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

1) I am new to laravel and want to integrate validation rules. My requirement is to make third field mandatory on basis of two other fields. Field C is required if both a and b are true. I have used *required_if* to put validation on basis of other single field but how can i use *required_if* to check two fields?

2) To achieve above functionality i tried custom validation rule as well. But it's working only if i will pull required rule alongwith.

For example:

```
'number_users' => 'required|custom_rule'   //working 
'number_users' => 'custom_rule'   //Not working
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [conditional rules](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) for that.

Here's a simple example:

```
$input = [
    'a' => true,
    'b' => true,
    'c' => ''
];

$rules = [
    'a' => 'required',
    'b' => 'required'
    // specify no rules for c, we'll do that below
];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

// now here's where the magic happens
$validator->sometimes('c', 'required', function($input){
    return ($input->a == true && $input->b == true);
});

dd($validator->passes()); // false in this case
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel evaluates each rule in the giver order. Let's say:

```
'number_users' => 'required|custom_a|custom_b'
```

`custom_b` rule will be evaluate when `required` and `custom_b` are true because these rules were already evaluated.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But i want only custom rule to be implemented not required one like i mentioned in my second code line?? Inside custom rule i think i can use required rule based on conditions.

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-if) you can make a complex `required_if` statement by using `requiredIf` mothod of validation Rule.

> If you would like to construct a more complex condition for the required_if rule, you may use the Rule::requiredIf method. This method accepts a boolean or a closure. When passed a closure, the closure should return true or false to indicate if the field under validation is required:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'number_users' => Rule::requiredIf(function () {
        return $this->input('input_a') == 1 && $this->input('input_b') == 2;
    }),
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a generic validator to test the AND operator.

```php
Validator::extend('required_multiple', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $isRequired = true;

    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($parameters) / 2; $i = $i + 2) {
        $parameter = $parameters[$i];
        $value = $parameters[$i + 1];

        if (in_array($value, ['true', 'false'])) {
            $value = (bool)$value;
        }

        if ($validator->getData()[$parameter] !== $value) {
            $isRequired = false;
        }
    }

    if (!$isRequired || ($isRequired && $validator->getData()[$attribute])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Then in your controller rules:

```
'phone_input_label' => 'required_multiple:goal,lead-capture,phone_input_active,true|string',
```

This will make "phone_input_label" required if goal is equal to "lead-capture" **and** phone_input_active is true.

The only problem with that custom validator is that you **need** to send all parameters. If "phone_input_label" is not sent in the request, it won't even pass through the custom validator, not sure why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer

```
 'field3' => 'required_if:field_1 | required_if:field_2'
```

Comment: I imagine it would help @dirtyhandsphp if you provided a bit more explaination for why your answer works.

Comment: `required_if` requires two arguments.

Comment: Note that this performs an OR validation.

Answer (score -4):

Take a look at the laravel validation docs which I pasted a link below, you can use required_if, required_without and others to suit your needs.

[See the Laravel Validation Docs Here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation)