# Laravel: required_if with an AND check

Tags: laravel

Consider this validation:

```php
Route::post('/validate', function (Request $request): JsonResponse {
    $validated = $request->validate([
        "insurance_plan" => ["required", "in:Commerical Insurance,Government,Uninsured"],
        "insurance_hasSecondaryPrescriptionInsurance" => ["boolean"],
        'insurance_secondaryPrescriptionName' => ['required_if:insurance_hasSecondaryPrescriptionInsurance,true', 'required_if:insurance_plan,Government,Commericial Insurance' ]
    ]);

    return response()->json([
        'validated' => $validated
    ]);
});
```

For `insurance_secondaryPrescriptionName`, I'm looking to do a AND validation. If insurance_plan has those value 'Uninsured' AND insurance_hasSecondaryPrescriptionInsurance is true.

So if I send out this request it should pass validation:

```
POST https://localhost/api/validate
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

{
    "insurance_plan": "Uninsured",
    "insurance_hasSecondaryPrescriptionInsurance": true,
    "insurance_secondaryPrescriptionName": ""
}
```

Does this require a custom validator or is there a preexisting validation I can use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add laravel multiple required\_if (like AND Logical)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564383/how-to-add-laravel-multiple-required-if-like-and-logical)

Answer (score 1):

To use an "AND" logic or to add more complex validation logics you need to use `Rule::requiredIf()` to create a custom rule validator using a closure (https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-required-if):

```php
Route::post('/validate', function (Request $request): JsonResponse {
    $validated = $request->validate([
        // ...
        'insurance_secondaryPrescriptionName' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
            // your own logic
            return true; // or false;
        })
    ]);

    return response()->json([
        'validated' => $validated
    ]);
});
```

Comment: This would work, except I could not use that method to implement the check (a restriction I should have mentioned in my question perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out by extending Validator (based off of this [How to use multi required_if in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609822/how-to-use-multi-required-if-in-laravel/60210528#60210528)).

```
        Validator::extend('required_multiple', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            $pool = [];

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($parameters); $i = $i + 2) {
                $parameter = $parameters[$i];
                $condition = $parameters[$i + 1];

                if (in_array($condition, ['true', 'false'])) {
                    $condition = (bool) $condition;
                }

                $data = $validator->getData();

                if (strpos($condition, '|') !== false) {

                    $haystack = explode('|', $condition);
                    if (in_array($data[$parameter], $haystack)) {
                        $pool[] = true;
                    } else {
                        $pool[] = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($data[$parameter] === $condition) {
                        $pool[] = true;
                    } else {
                        $pool[] = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (in_array(false, $pool)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            };
        });
    }
```

And I could use it in my code like so:

```
'some-field' => ['required_multiple:insurance_plan,Government|Commerical Insurance,insurance_hasSecondaryPrescriptionInsurance,true']
```